# Need to reconnect to network repeatedly in order to access internet

Tags: networking, wireless, laptop

ubuntu has been acting funny on my laptop. It automatically loses connection (still is connected to the wireless network though, as shown on the top bar) but I need to reconnect to the network in order to connect to the internet. I've tried turning off power management. This has been happening more often now. Please help. Comment about what all input you'd need in order to diagnose my issue.

P.S: It disconnected twice while submitting this question, and as usual I had to reconnect to the network in order to regain internet access.

Here goes the information (thanks @mikewhatever)
http://paste.ubuntu.com/23363106/

Comment: Start here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos

Comment: @mikewhatever done that. please look into it?

Comment: There are some interesting clues in `dmesg`, see if [this forum thread](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2192364) helps. Also, try to use wpa2 AES only.

Comment: @mikewhatever none of those really worked :( anything else you could suggest?